# can't find multiple values in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, multiple-results

I have a DB full of players and I am trying to create a page to register them into a specific tournament. The tournament director will search for players by username (which is only "firstname.lastname").

The problem I'm experiencing is that when I run loop to echo each $players[$x] it only gives the ID for the first matching DB record, and repeats the number once for each match. Rather than returning ID 7, 11, 26 it will return 7, 7, 7. Please can someone explain why?

I have written the following code in a .php file:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['newsearch']) === true && empty($_POST['newsearch'] === false)){
require 'dbconnect.php';
$term = $_POST['newsearch'];
$terms = "%" . $term . "%";

$query = ("SELECT PlayerID FROM players WHERE Username LIKE '$terms'");
$run_query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
$search = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query);
$players = array ();

    do{
    //Get data from players table
    $PlayerID = $search['PlayerID'];
array_push ($players, $PlayerID);        
    }
        while ($dbsearch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query));}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more that one `fetch` for the same query, replace the code after `$run_query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);` with this code:

```
 $players = array ();
 while ($dbsearch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query))
     {
         array_push($players, $dbsearch['PlayerID']);;
     }
```

Comment: @Tunna182 if this has solved your question please mark it as accepted by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself

Comment: Thanks mate. I tried to accept straight away but it said I had to wait a few minutes. You've helped heaps (it's accepted now).

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is wrong

```
$query = ("SELECT PlayerID FROM players WHERE Username LIKE '$terms'");
$run_query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
$search = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query);
$players = array ();

do{
    //Get data from players table
    $PlayerID = $search['PlayerID'];
    array_push ($players, $PlayerID);        
    }
    while ($search = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query));
}
```

Put `$search` instead of `$dbsearch`

```
$search = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query))
```

Note : your query is vulnerable to SQLI